# Elixir: Behaviour of Backspace in iex

Tags: elixir, readline, elixir-iex

I'm using Elixir 1.15.0 with Erlang/OTP 26 on Arch Linux. I haven't configured anything; I'm just using the default setup.

When I type the following code in IEx:

```
i <- [1, 2, 3], j <- [10, 20, 30], into: %{}, do: "#{i}*{j}
```

And then press `[Backspace]`, because I forgot the `#` before `{j}`, the result looks as follows:

```
i <- [1, 2, 3], j <- [10, 20, 30], into: %{}, do: "#{
```

Not only `}` (what I'd expect) or `{j}` (which would be convenient) was deleted, but also the `i}` part that was correct.

I noticed that `[Backspace]` in IEx deletes not only single characters, but entire symbols. This behaviour is not useful for me, because all the other REPLs I'm using behave differently.

How can I get my regular backspace function back in IEx?

Edit 1: The backspace character works as usual in the terminal outside of `iex`. My `$TERM` is `xterm-256color`. I also tested it with my default terminal `qterminal` as well as `xterm`, in which `iex` misbehaves the same way.

Edit 2: I have the exact same behaviour in `erl`, so it might be an Erlang issue, not one of the Elixir project. What's the common ground of those two REPLs?

Comment: I just tried this on Ubuntu (Erlang/OTP 26) with Elixir 1.15.6 and I didn't see the behavior you mentioned.  One thought--try `echo $TERM` and see what you get.  It seems more likely to be an issue with your terminal emulation than Elixir.  For me it reports xterm-256color (from `echo $TERM`).  I'd also try using the backspace at a regular shell prompt and see what happens.  I mean I suspect it's more likely to be your terminal emulation.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I also get `xterm-256color`. Deleting more than one character is probably a feature. But I'd rather not use it, because the behaviour is unique to `iex`, i.e. I'm not used to it.

Comment: I doubt it's a feature and I doubt it's intentional.  I've never seen that happen from Iex and I've been using Elixir for _years_.  Are you positive that it only happens with Iex?  What about if you try the same thing in the erlang shell (that is, start `erl` and try typing/erasing)?  Iex relies on the Erlang shell so if you _don't_ see the behavior in the Erlang shell then it's something Elixir specific.  Also make sure if you have an .iex.exs file present that you remove it temporarily.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci That's it! In `erl`, I get exactly the same issue! So the issue is rather to be located in Erlang.

Comment: I don't know enough about the Erl interactions with the terminal to help!  If I were you that's what I'd be searching for--odd backspace behavior with the Erl Repl.  If possible see if you can try it with the most recent version of Erlang.

Comment: See my edits on my response--may be a way to figure out if a change to OTP 26 is responsible for the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [issue](https://github.com/erlang/otp/issues/7776) has been resolved in Erlang OTP 26.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Arch Linux, but I couldn't reproduce your issue using Docker:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM archlinux:latest
RUN pacman --noconfirm -Sy --needed elixir
ENTRYPOINT ["iex"]
```

Building:

```bash
$ docker build . -t arch_elixir
```

Running:

```bash
$ docker run --rm -it arch_elixir
Erlang/OTP 26 [erts-14.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]

Interactive Elixir (1.15.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> i <- [1, 2, 3], j <- [10, 20, 30], into: %{}, do: "#{i}*{j
```

Answer (score 1):

To consolidate some of the clarifications I asked for in comments so they'll be more obvious if anyone searches for this:

1.) Check the terminal emulation you're using.  One simple way to do this is `echo $TERM`.  This is information which will help others to reproduce (or not) the behavior in question.

2.) Try using the backspace at the terminal prompt.  If you see the extra characters wiped at the terminal prompt then it's not Elixir and you should look elsewhere for an answer.

3.) If you have an `.iex.exs` file present, temporarily rename it or move it to another directory.  This *may* affect the behavior of the backspce.

---

EDIT:

Given what the original poster has shared about this behavior, I think this may be pertinent:

https://www.erlang.org/patches/otp-26.0

I can't link it directly but this portion:
OTP-17932

Note especially this:

> The TTY/terminal subsystem has been rewritten by moving more code to
> Erlang from the old linked-in driver and implementing all the I/O
> primitives needed in a NIF instead.

And this seems like it may be worth trying to see if it affects the behavior you're seeing:

> -- Standard I/O now always defaults to unicode mode if supported. Previously the default was latin1 if the runtime system had been
> started with -oldshell or -noshell (for example in an escript). To
> send raw bytes over standard out, one now explicitly has to specify
> *io:setopts(standard_io, [{encoding, latin1}])*.

(Emphasis is mine.)

Comment: 1) `xterm-256color`, 2) works as intended, 3) wasn't present

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem on Manjaro-KDE.
I found though that it has to do with the terminal.

When running in Terminology i get the described behaviour, when running in konsole it behaves as expected

Comment: I reported [this issue](https://github.com/erlang/otp/issues/7776). Unfortunately, the according answer was down voted and then deleted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).