# Getting a single character from the console without hitting enter in Elixir/Erlang

Tags: console, erlang, elixir, tty

I upgraded my Elixir app from version 1.8 to 1.15.7.  Now my code that enables getting a single character from the console without having to hit enter does not work anymore:

```
{:ok, Port.open({:spawn, "tty_sl -c -e"}, [:binary, :eof])}
```

I have Erlang 26.0.2 installed but it seems tty_sl is no longer present.  Is there another way to get a single character without hitting enter?

Comment: For what it's worth this Q & A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77253655/elixir-behaviour-of-backspace-in-iex  may be sort of related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to tell what you are actually trying to achieve, but yes, `tty_sl` [has been removed from `OTP 26`](https://www.erlang.org/news/164#the-shell) in favor of internal shell handling.

What you probably need, would be to spawn a regular `tty` and then send [`stty raw -echo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832933/what-does-stty-raw-echo-do-on-os-x) command to it right after it’s started.